# Example of registering classes for Objectify using ServletContextListener

Tags: google-app-engine, web.xml, objectify, servletcontextlistener

I have read a couple of articles, including Objectify's documentation in Github, that the best practice on registering classes for Objectify purpose is to use ServletContextListener in web.xml.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find any example for the Google App Engine (endpoint) scenario.

Does anyone have an example that I can follow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I am looking for is [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/using-datastore-objectify#the_helper_file_ofyhelperjava): ...I already have the setup you suggested, however, it will occasionally give me the "class not registered error"

Answer (score 0):

First, enable ObjectifyFilter in web.xml if you haven't done so already

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then what I do is to create a class like this:

```
public class OfyService {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OfyService.class.getName());

    static {
        try {
            ObjectifyService.register(EntityA.class);
            /* ... more entities ... */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
        }
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }

    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

In my endpoint methods I then use Objectify with `OfyService.ofy().load().type(EntityA.class)...`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Listener to your web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>[Fully qualified name of your class]</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And implements the ServletContextListener, and start to register your entities as below:

```
public class BootstrapListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ObjectifyFactory factory= ObjectifyService.factory();
        factory.register(**[YOUR_ENTITY]**.class);
    }
```